# Whitespace chars of a string can't be replaced in Java 8

Tags: java, replace

I've to filter specific containers from a vCard ("*.vcf" file). I filter for lines which contain the substring `Photo;` if matched, the lines until a specific String `==` gets saved in my `imageEncoding` String. Somehow, if I want to replace the whitespaces of `imageEncoding`with `""` nothing gets replaced.

**Example of the "container":**

```
PHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64;JPEG:/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAIBAQEBAQIBAQE
 CAgICAgQDAgICAgUEBAMEBgUGBgYFBgYGBwkIBgcJBwYGCAsICQoKCgoKBggLDAsKDAkKCgr/==
```

**Code snippet:**

```
else if(line.contains("PHOTO;")){
                String imageEncoding = line;

                while(true){
                    line = reader.readLine();
                    if (line.contains("==")){
                        imageEncoding = imageEncoding+line;
                        break;
                    }
                    imageEncoding = imageEncoding+line;
                }
                //imageEncoding.replaceAll(" ","");
                imageEncoding.replaceAll("\\s","");
                System.out.println(imageEncoding);

            }
```

**Output with " ":**

```
PHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64;JPEG:/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAIBAQEBAQIBAQE
 CAgICAgQDAgICAgUEBAMEBgUGBgYFBgYGBwkIBgcJBwYGCAsICQoKCgoKBggLDAsKDAkKCgr/==
```

**Output with \s**:

```
PHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64;JPEG:/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAIBAQEBAQIBAQE
 CAgICAgQDAgICAgUEBAMEBgUGBgYFBgYGBwkIBgcJBwYGCAsICQoKCgoKBggLDAsKDAkKCgr/==
```

**What it should be:**

```
PHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64;JPEG:/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAIBAQEBAQIBAQE
CAgICAgQDAgICAgUEBAMEBgUGBgYFBgYGBwkIBgcJBwYGCAsICQoKCgoKBggLDAsKDAkKCgr/==
```

The string is many lines longer, this is only a snippet. I tried to replace `\\s` but that also not worked.

Comment: Please post the code you used to try and replace `\\s` that did not work.

Comment: I would suggest you use replace instead of replaceAll, since you are not using a regular expression as a parameter

Comment: For your information, base64 has no obligation to end with == and jpegs encoded in base64 have no such obligation either.

Comment: @kumesana Ok but when I want to use this string as source for my `Image` object do I even need to replace the whitespaces?

Comment: You certainly cannot use it without decoding the base64 first, so that's not really a question of being the source for an Image object. Some base64 decoders will flat-out ignore whitespace (as your case is typical) and some will need you to clean the whitespace first. Check how it is for your decoder of choice.

Comment: @kumesana thanks for the Information I'll take a look at it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write

```
imageEncoding = imageEncoding.replaceAll(" ","");
```

Strings are immutable in Java.

Answer (score 5):

1. replaceAll is superfluous here; it's first argument is a regexp, and you don't apparently need that. Just use .replace which, despite the name, also replaces all.
2. replaceAll (and replace) don't modify the string (strings in java are immutable). They make a new one. So, instead of `imageEncoding.replaceAll(" ", "")`, try: `imageEncoding = imageEncoding.replace(" ", "")`